# JSDoc description not showing on function returned in object

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a problem that when i return the border function inside the style object the parameter descriptions just say **ANY**. I know it works when returning just the function by itself but i want to organize by returning objects with a group of functions. Is there any way to to that?

```
var GDL = (function () {
    
    //border defualt
    let border_style = ["solid"]
    let border_width = [2]
    let border_color = "black"
    let border_radius = 0

    //style functions
    /**
     * Add border style to canvas. Array are 1 [all], 2 [sides, top and bottom] or 4 [left, top, right, bottom] long
     * @param {[String]} style 
     * @param {[Number]} width 
     * @param {string} color 
     * @param {Number} borderRadius 
     */
    function border(style = border_style, width = border_width, color = border_color, borderRadius = border_radius){

    }

    style = {border}
    return {style}
})()

let f = GDL
f.style.border()
```

I have tried to google if there is any way to keep JSDoc params when returning an object with functions but i couldn't find anything. Also looked through simular questions but i could not get it to work

Comment: Declare it as a method and put the jsdoc on the method? `styles = { /** … */ border(…) { … }}`

Comment: Your variable `style` doesn't seem to be explicitly declared. Fixing this showed the JSDoc as expected for me.

Comment: explicitly declaring style does fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of "post answers as answers, not comments":

Your variable `style` doesn't seem to be explicitly declared. Fixing this showed the JSDoc as expected for me.